# I have no idea what this test is looking for

Tags: test-class

```
assertEquals(Modifier.STATIC | Modifier.PRIVATE, d.getClass().getDeclaredField("TYPES").getModifiers());
```

I have a fixed array that I wrote as a field like this:
    `private String[] TYPES;`

and I initialized it like this:

```
   TYPES= new String[3];
   TYPES[0]="surveillance";
   TYPES[1]="missile";
   TYPES[2]="bombing";
```

Am i doing something wrong?